# Wordpress Own Rewrite Rules

Tags: plugin-development, rewrite-rules, regex

i am trying to rewrite a URL with the following code in functions.php

```
add_action('init', function()
 {
    add_rewrite_rule('/agbz\/(\w*)\/\?page=(\w*)&memberID=([a-z]{1}\d*)&land=(\w*)&fa=(\w*)&vorname=(\w*)&nachname=(\w*)/miu', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]&page=member&memberID=$matches[3]&land=$matches[4]&fa=$matches[5]&vorname=$matches[6]&nachname=$matches[7]', 'top');
 });
```

My URL is :

> domain.de/agbz/userprofile/?page=member&memberID=Z4911331&land=deutschland&fa=zahnarzt&urltitel&vorname=Henryk&nachname=Donnerstag

Can someone help me out of this? The URL is the same as before

Comment: Just because WP will accept a rewrite rule and show the right things when you use it, doesn't mean that all the URLs it generates in templates and for posts will use it. Permalinks won't change unless you change them, it's a separate system

Comment: but how can i do that correctly?